I cannot read from Firebase Realtime Database Emulator (but I can when using the production database)
I am a new Android developer and am using Firebase Emulator to test my project during development. My project uses both Firebase Auth and Firebase Realtime Database. When connected to the emulator, Firebase Auth works as expected, and I can even write data to the Realtime db emulator. However, I cannot read from it. When I try to, I get the following warnings in Android Studio:

pc_1 - Provided authentication credentials are invalid. This usually indicates your FirebaseApp instance was not initialized correctly. Make sure your google-services.json file has the correct firebase_url and api_key. You can re-download google-services.json from https://console.firebase.google.com/.\
Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.

I initialize the Firebase emulators as follows:
Firebase.auth.useEmulator("10.0.2.2", 9099)
Firebase.database.useEmulator("10.0.2.2", 9000)

I have re-downloaded google-services.json, but this had no effect. I have checked the values in the default FirebaseApp instance, and they match what is in google-services.json. I have uninstalled and reinstalled the Firebase CLI tools, but this did not help. I also know this is not a problem with my security rules as the issue persists even when I set read and write to true.
What's more strange is I have no problem when using the production database. I can both write to and read from the prod db. Has anyone had a similar problem and could help out? I am now forced to test on my production database which is obviously not ideal.

Please edit your question to show how you initialize Firebase, and specifically how you tell the SDK to connect to the emulator - which is shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_rtdb#java

@FrankvanPuffelen edited, thank you.

Have you checked for a race condition? Is your "use the emulator" instruction always running before your attempt to perform the read action? This error might be because Firebase is trying to use your emulated auth token to talk to the production Firebase Realtime Database instead of your emulator (or vice versa). Consider adding some logs that allow you to confirm that your emulator connection is made before your attempt to read the data.

@samthecodingman thank you for bringing that up! My database reference was being created before the emulators were set up which was the cause. Still don't know why it only broke reading from the emulated db, but I'm glad it's fixed.

Figured it out. My database reference was being created before the emulators were set up which was the cause. Still don't know why it only broke reading from the emulated db and not writing, but I'm glad it's fixed.
